# Resizing and animating SVG clipPath

Tags: animation, svg, mask, clip-path

i have a SVG that i use as a mask (via clipPath) over an image
my idea was to use the SVG mask as a revealer for the image, by scaling it from 0 to big enouoght to reveal the image
i made this sample

```
#ima  {
  clip-path: url(#yes);
  width:800px;
height:800px;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

https://codepen.io/lenna-the-vuer/pen/GRyvBEa

but it looks the SVG can't be modified or positioned.

I already made some reveal using a basic clip path, by animating the path itslef
but i can't do it with a complex SVG
any sugggestion?

Comment: Seems to work for me. I'm using Firefox.

Comment: @RobertLongson i'm working on the pen using animateTransform, but it does not work as expetected, also i need to programmatically animate it (using GSAP)
at the moment it looks like i can animate the transform:scale(...) property of the clipPath, but it works from the top left corner

Comment: your question says "can't be modified or positioned" now you're saying it "works from the top left corner" so your question seems misleading. Perhaps you could rewrite it to be clearer as to what it does now and what you want it to do instead. You seem to have edited it so that it doesn't animate at all now. Please put your complete testcase [in the question itself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: @RobertLongson im currently working on it and tried the animateTransform (now i removed it) so it looks like i cant position and move it using css property

Comment: Well we can't really answer a moving target.